# Is fixed-top/fixed-bottom + inner div's with fixed height the right approach?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, fixed

I am trying to create stackoverflow-style app with fixed menu and footer panels and the inner div which create browser scroll (as necessary).

I just wanted to ask if the following code is right to achieve the mentioned scenario? fixed-top/fixed-bottom are styles from the Bootstrap4. I see that I have to use fixed constants in my HTML/Style code in my approach, is it OK.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="fixed-top" style="height: 50px; border: 2px solid black">
      Header
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="height: 50px"></div>
      (1) The protection of natural persons in relation to the processing of personal data is a fundamental right. Article 8(1) of the Charter of Fundamental Rights of the European Union (the ‘Charter’) and Article 16(1) of the Treaty on the Functioning of
      the European Union (TFEU) provide that everyone has the right to the protection of personal data concerning him or her.
      <div style="height: 50px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-bottom" style="height: 50px; border: 2px solid black">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please provide some CSS to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Bootstrap class please use below css where the header and footer
will have fixed height and position absolute.

```
    html body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      html body .container-fluid.body-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 30px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
      fixed-header {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          background-color: #4C4;
          height: 50px;
      }
      fixed-bottom {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: #4C4;
          height: 30px;
      }

 <div class="fixed-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
      Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
      Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
      Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
      Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
      Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-bottom">
      Footer
    </div>
```